# calling optional delegate methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, option-type

i created a delegate for a class

```
@protocol gameDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(void)gameStarted;
@required
@end
```

now in my game object i called this method:

```
[self.delegate gameStarted];
```

so now, if i initiate this object anywhere and set the delegate everything works fine until the gameStated gets called, because its not implemented in the main object where the game object is created (because its optional).

i tried some variations of this

```
if(![self.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(gameStarted)]) {
    //[self.delegate gameStarted];
}
```

but this is not working for me.
any ideas how to make this "really" optional?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Omit the negation from your `if` statement:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(gameStarted)]) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: oh my god :D i used this if statement first for an early return if it does not respond to, and then i just copied it for this method. what a stupid mistake. thanks

Comment: note that your delegate will have to conform to NSOBject: @protocol XXX <NSObject> for this to work

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this in swift, I recommend the following:

```
@objc protocol MyDelegate {

optional func optionalMethod()

}

class MyClass : MyDelegate {

// optionalMethod() does not have to be declared

}
```

Then to call the `optional` on your `delegate` object, simple use `if delegate.optionalMethod?(){}`

Answer (score 0):

Checking if a delegate implements an optional method and then calling it is such a common pattern that I use a preprocessor macro `SAFE_CALL` that checks `respondToSelector:` and then calls the method.

The macro is:

```
#define SAFE_CALL(obj,method) \
([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(method)] ? [obj method] : nil)
```

and it is used like this:

```
SAFE_CALL(sourceDelegate, refresh)
// or 
NSString *response = SAFE_CALL(object, responseValue)
```

Note this version works only with methods with no parameters.

Originally it was implemented as a C function, but that causes warnings with `performSelector` leaks when using ARC. As a preprocessor macro it works exactly as expected.